# Clamav: command not found

Tags: command-line, apt, clamav, clamtk

I installed clamav and clamtk. clamtk GUI is visible but seems to do nothing.
If I do:
clamav on the CLI I get clamav: command not found.
If you do:
sudo clamav clamav-freshclam I also get:clamav: command not found.
If I do :
freshclam, I get: ERROR: Can't open/parse the config file /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
Reinstalling clamav and clamtk (sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk) does not help.

Who can help?

Output of sudo apt update:

```
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for jan: 
Hit:1 htt p://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 htt p://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                                                                                                                                       
Hit:4 htt p://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                
Hit:5 htt p://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Hit:6 htt p://ppa.launchpad.net/jconti/recent-notifications/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                
Hit:7 htt ps://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                     
Ign:8 htt p://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:9 htt ps://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                                          
Ign:10 htt p://ppa.launchpad.net/qos/pulseaudio-dlna/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                    
Get:3 htt p://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15,4 kB]                          
Err:11 ht tp://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu bionic Release                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 80]
Err:12 htt p://ppa.launchpad.net/qos/pulseaudio-dlna/ubuntu bionic Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 80]
Hit:13 htt ps://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease                  
Hit:14 htt p://apt.galliumos.org bismuth InRelease                                    
Err:3 htt p://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 241FE6973B765FAE
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'htt p://ppa.launchpad.net/qos/pulseaudio-dlna/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: htt p://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 241FE6973B765FAE
E: The repository 'htt p://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Output of sudo apt install clamav

```
sudo apt install clamav
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
clamav is already the newest version (0.105.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

I added spaces in the urls  because I am not allowed to use much links
I use GalliumOS, which is Xubuntu for Chromebooks. Version 3.1

Comment: what is the output from `sudo apt install --reinstall clamav`?

Comment: jan@galliumos:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall clamav
[sudo] password for jan: 
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
Herinstalleren van clamav is niet mogelijk omdat het niet opgehaald kan worden.
0 opgewaardeerd, 0 nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 3 niet opgewaardeerd.
This output is in Dutch; the last part translates as: reinstall of clamav is not possible because it cannot be picked up.

Comment: so you *don't* have clamav installed. of course it won't work. You have to figure out why "it cannot be fetched". It would be very helpful to post output from `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install clamav` in English. You can run `export LANGUAGE=en_US` before running apt commands to temporarily (until you close and re-open terminal) switch language to English.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please, [edit] your question and add all the requested information, ___into your original question___ text.

Comment: The output is much too long for this comment window. How can I send a 4000+ character message to this forum? 
OK I see the answer now :-)

Comment: I added the requested information to the original question text

Comment: Gallium OS is not an official Ubuntu version and it's not supported on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a package is not always the name of the executable. To see the list of files installed by a package, run `dpkg -L package-name`. In this case, the executables are:

```
$ dpkg -L clamav | grep /bin/    
/usr/bin/clambc
/usr/bin/clamscan
/usr/bin/clamsubmit
/usr/bin/sigtool
```

The one you're looking for is most likely `clamscan`, to scan a file or directory for virus. For example:

```
$ clamscan /tmp/clam/     
/tmp/clam/foo: OK
/tmp/clam/bar: OK

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 8621967
Engine version: 0.103.6
Scanned directories: 1
Scanned files: 2
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 15.478 sec (0 m 15 s)
Start Date: 2022:07:13 19:23:30
End Date:   2022:07:13 19:23:45
```

Comment: Have solved it by  using App-grid package manager. But not satisfied because it is not clear to me why it did not work with apt-get install...

Comment: In a suggested edit, you show that you have a file `/usr/local/bin/clamscan` instead of the normal /usr/bin/ one. Please post the output of `apt policy clamav` in your question, you apparently installed a non-standard version of the package.

Comment: Thanks, I just used the "normal" clamav installation commands. I cannot do the suggested check because in the meantime I used package manager Appgrid to install the package. And now it works fine.